# Why changeResourceRecordSets gets not authorized to access this resource?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a new record in Route 53 of type Alias to tell Route 53 to sue CloudFront to serve the site. I'm trying to do this using the following code:

```
let options = {
    ChangeBatch: {
        Changes: [{
            Action: "CREATE",
            ResourceRecordSet: {
                AliasTarget: {
                    DNSName: '12kjh31k2hj3.cloudfront.net',
                    EvaluateTargetHealth: false,
                    HostedZoneId: 'JKEJWQHKJQWKK'
                },
                Name: 'example.com',
                Type: "A"
            }
        }],
        Comment: "S3 Hosted Site"
    },
    HostedZoneId: 'Z2FDTNDATAQYW2' // Fixed ID CloudFront distribution
};

route53.changeResourceRecordSets(options, function(error, data) {

    //
    //  1.  Check if there was an error
    //
    if(error)
    {
        return reject(error);
    }

    //
    //  -> Move to the next chain
    //
    return resolve(container);

});
```

When I run this I get:

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::1234567:user/cli_s3_hosting is not authorized to access this resource
```

If I use IAM Policy Simulator I have no issues as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

I also tried to add `AdminFullAccess` and still I get the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you need to swap the values of HostedZoneId's i.e. Z2FDTNDATAQYW2 should appear first and then your route53 hosted zone.
The error is appearing since you are trying to change RR set of the CF distribution which does not belong to your account.

Comment: You are right, that was the problem, thank you very much for catching this one for me :)

Comment: No worries...glad to hear it's working, I have added my previous comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to swap the values of HostedZoneId's i.e. [Z2FDTNDATAQYW2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html#changeResourceRecordSets-property) should appear first and then your route53 hosted zone. The error is appearing since you are trying to change resource record set of the CF distribution hosted zone (Z2FDTNDATAQYW2) which does not belong to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, for anybody getting this error from the CLI:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id  ABCDEFGHIJKLM --change-batch file://wilcards.json    # this zone-id is for YOUR domain (eg my-domain.com.)
```

The HostedZoneId here is one from this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

```
{
    "Comment": "CREATE *.sub.my-domain.com. ",
    "Changes": [{
    "Action": "UPSERT",
            "ResourceRecordSet": {
                        "Name": "\\052.sub.my-domain.com.",
                        "Type": "A",
                    "AliasTarget": {
                        "HostedZoneId": "Z1H1FL5HABSF5",
                        "DNSName": "dualstack.my-elb-or-other-endpoint.aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com.",
                        "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
                    }
            }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am having admin access and still not authorized to run the command.

The reason was that I have MFA enabled on my AWS account and the same has to be done for aws-cli.

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/) might help you in setting up the same.