# certificatemanager:changeResourceRecordSets user is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

Trying to create an SSL certificate using Amazon Certificate Manager, as per here -

https://medium.com/swlh/aws-website-hosting-with-cloudformation-guide-36cac151d1af

I have a deployment user with the following policy -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*",
                "s3:*",
                "route53:*",
                "acm:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I deploy I get the following -

```
API: certificatemanager:changeResourceRecordSets User #{my_IAM_deploy_user} is not authorized to access this resource
```

How come I am getting this error despite `acm:*` access ?

(wondering if related to [Why changeResourceRecordSets gets not authorized to access this resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704122/why-changeresourcerecordsets-gets-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource) but can't see exactly how)

(Cloudformation template below)

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: cloudfront-route53-demo-cert
Parameters:
  DomainName:
    Type: String
  HostedZoneId:
    Type: String
    Default: Z1BKCTXD74EZPE  # eu-west-1; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints
Outputs:
  CertificateARN:
    Value:
      Ref: Certificate  # returns ARN
Resources:
  Certificate:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName:
        Ref: DomainName
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName:
            Ref: DomainName
          HostedZoneId:
            Ref: HostedZoneId
      ValidationMethod: DNS
```

Comment: `changeResourceRecordSets` is related to AWS Route 53. Is your AWS CFN template modifying AWS Route53 RecordSet? if yes, then your IAM user will need permission to perform action `route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets`

Comment: as shown above the IAM user has permissions for both `acm:*` and `route53:*`

Comment: Do you have modify access to HostedZoneId used here?

Comment: why would the template want to `ChangeResourceRecordSets` ? Is it because the record set is in `eu-west-1` but the certificate needs to be created in `us-east-1`, and the region needs to be changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood what `HostedZoneId` was. I thought it was some kind of route53 region- specific singleton but (doh) turns out it just the id of a route53 HostedZone I had created. Kinda obvious really.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error in my stack...
I don't see how your "Answer" really answered the question.  Can you be more specific about what you did to eliminate the error, considering you already have full acm and route53 permissions?

Comment: @KickinMhl You have to manually create a HostedZone in route53 and copy the HostedZoneId over.